# How to write column by column using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a map like following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> finalDataSet = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

It has data like following:

```
{Name1={CurrentUserStory=[AB-1413, AB-1504], CUS_Status=[In Testing, Ready for Deployment], SubTask=[AB-1547, AB-1508], ST_Status=[In Development, Done], TimeSpent=[19800, 23400]},Name2={CurrentUserStory=[AB-1377, AB-149],CUS_Status=[Ready for Testing, Ready for Development],SubTask=[AB-1545, AB-1510], ST_Status=[Ready for Testing, Closed],TimeSpent=[25200, 5400]}}
```

The above data I want to write into excel in this below format.

[image]

When am trying to write these data to excel only "TimeSpent" Column is writing and all columns are empty.Here is my code:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet("CSG_Report");
Row row = sh.createRow(2);
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> m : finalDataSet.entrySet()) {
    int col=1;
    row= sh.createRow(index);
    int userindex=index;
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> innerMap:m.getValue().entrySet())
    {
        index = userindex;
        List<String> val=innerMap.getValue();
        row= sh.createRow(index);
        for (String string : val) {
            row= sh.createRow(index);
            row=sh.getRow(index);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(string);
            index++;
        }
        col++;
    }
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new
        File("D:\\Output.xlsx"));
wb.write(out);
out.close();
wb.close();
```

Please help me to get it done. Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK you can't, it's "row-based", but if the number of columns/lines is fixed, then you can create all the cell needed and fill them later with some loop

Comment: It's row based but if you can control your sizes, you can make it column based... Simply imagine that you have only 1 column and then, append another column to this one.

Comment: Your data structure is not suitable. One would consider this design only if the number of values in each attribute can vary, in which case you will not be able to draw them on Excel in any easy way. Instead of this, you could make a `class` with properties `CurrentUserStory`, `CUS_Status`, `SubTask`, `ST_Status` and map them against name, your job will be a lot easier with that.

Comment: You mean to say if  `List<String> val=innerMap.getValue();` val.size() is static then we can able to do. Am I correct @canillas and @RC

Comment: There is nothing called Column in POI... its just row and individual cell within that row. So if you are trying to iterate within each column and each time creating new row... this will not work...Once any row is created... it will overwrite the previous instance, and so at the end you are getting only last instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution for my issue. 
Here is my code....

```
int columnNum=1;
    int fRow=2;
    List<String> cvals = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> m : finalDataSet.entrySet()) {
        Row row = sh.createRow(fRow);
        Cell cell1=row.createCell(0);
        cell1.setCellValue("Name1");

        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> innerMap:m.getValue().entrySet()){
            cvals=innerMap.getValue();

             int tempHeight=cvals.size();
             int temp=fRow;
             for (String cval : cvals) {
                 Row row2;
                 if(sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1>temp-1)
                    {

                        row2=sh.getRow(temp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row2=sh.createRow(temp);
                    }
                 Cell cell3=row2.createCell(columnNum);
                 cell3.setCellValue(cval);
                 temp=temp+1;
            }
             columnNum=columnNum+1; 
        }
        fRow=fRow+cvals.size();
        columnNum=1;
    }
```